# a condition inside except?

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there a way to put a condition inside an exception? for example:

```
while True:
    try:
        p1guess = int(input("enter guess here: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        if p1guess == "reveal":
            print(hidden)
```

my goal in this code is to enter a 4 digit number. however, if i enter "reveal", i would like the program to print hidden(a list containing 4 numbers) -unfortunately i cant find solutions to this

so i'm asking if there is a valid way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you wrote it, if an exception is raised, it is raised before the assignment to `p1guess` takes place, and therefor you cannot use the value in the except-clause.

What you can do is to first assign the input to a variable, then use it either way:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("enter guess here: ")
    try:
        p1guess = int(user_input)
        break
    except ValueError:
        if user_input == "reveal":
            print(hidden)
```

This is arguably slightly more pythonic, though:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("enter guess here: ")
    try:
        p1guess = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        if user_input == "reveal":
            print(hidden)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: i've got a question regarding the condition inside except. is there a possible way to include a condition that changes a value of a variable outside???

Comment: @user3921890 I believe that you could just edit the variable inside the except statement without any special code.